# Save zip file in storage s3 aws laravel 9

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3

I'm asking for your help because I can't figure out where the error is.
I'm creating a backup zip file of a folder in Laravel and I want to automatically save it on the Amazon S3 server. I've already set up the entire FyleSystem, ID keys etc.. the point is that now on the Amazon server it only saves the name of the file and not the archive .zip, can I ask for your help to understand why it doesn't save the entire archive but only the name?

This is code

```
  $zip = new ZipArchive;

        $azienda = User::value('azienda');

        $fileName = time() . $azienda . ".zip";

        if ($zip->open(public_path($fileName), ZipArchive::CREATE) === TRUE) {

            $files = File::files(public_path('/images/images'));

            foreach ($files as $key => $value) {
                $relativeNameInZipFile = basename($value);
                $zip->addFile($value, $relativeNameInZipFile);

            }
            $zip->close();
        };

        Storage::disk('s3')->put('public/backup', $fileName);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zc6wu.png)

thanks a lot to everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Storage::put` takes either a string contents or a file *resource*. It does not take file *names*, and will treat it as the string it is.

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/filesystem#storing-files

```
Storage::disk('s3')->put('public/backup', fopen($filename, 'r'));
```

or, for lower memory usage, [stream it](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/filesystem#automatic-streaming):

```
Storage::disk('s3')->putFile('public/backup', new \Illuminate\Http\File($filename));
```

Comment: hey can I ask you something else?

I inserted the function into a daily schedule, the zip file is fine but it gives me a "NUL" error 2>&1

I have many schedules on the server, I've never had this error, why shouldn't it move it like it does in the normal controller?

Comment: Storage::disk('s3')->put('public/backup', fopen($filename, 'r')); with controller OK ! but with scheduler jobs Fail.. what could be the problem ?

Comment: I'd bet pathing or permissions issues. Consider using `storage_path($filename)` (presuming you make the .zip files in the storage folder) to get the full path to the file.

Comment: it still gives me the error with storage_path()

Comment: what else can I try? it doesn't make sense with the controller ok and with scheduler no?

Comment: I correct it, it gives me the string in s3 again and not the file with storage_path

Comment: do you have any other ideas?

Comment: `storage_path($filename)` should replace `$filename`, not the entire `fopen()` or `new File` calls.

Comment: Storage::disk('s3')->put('public' .  $fileName, fopen(storage_path($fileName), 'r')); Like this ?

Comment: Storage::disk('s3')->put('public' . $fileName, fopen(storage_path($fileName), 'r')); so it gives me the error schedule fail

Comment: solved like this: Storage::disk('s3')->put('public' . $fileName, fopen(public_path($fileName), 'r'));

Comment: @Moreno Consider the security implications of putting these .zip files in the `public` folder. You may want to consider a different location.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for joining us. Are you talking about security on Laravel or S3?
Unfortunately I'm new to these things...

Comment: The Laravel side of things. By doing `$zip->open(public_path($fileName)`, you're putting your .zip file publicly accessible. As it's a backup, it may contain sensitive information and would be better located in the storage folder.

Comment: oh thanks so much for the advice, I hadn't thought of that, you're the best

Answer (score 0):

> Storage::disk('s3')->put('public/backup', $fileName);

You are storing file name instead of content!

Try this:

```php
$content = Storage::get($fileName);
Storage::disk('s3')->put('avatars/1', $content);
```

Comment: hey can I ask you something else? I inserted the function into a daily schedule, the zip file is fine but it gives me a "NUL" error 2>&1 I have many schedules on the server, I've never had this error, why shouldn't it move it like it does in the normal controller?